# standard process for developing datastage steps

Tags: datastage

I have experience using Pentaho Kettle and Talend Data Integration for ETL jobs and typically the high-level process for developing transformations is:

1. define source connections
2. define target connections
3. define transformation of data between source and target

What is the 'standard' high-level process for developing datastage jobs?  Is it similar to the process identified above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same. If you know the basic concepts of an ETL tool, they apply to all of the tools.

The three steps you listed are, however, very high level. Depending on what you're trying to do, that list can be increased quite dramatically.